# Why is Angularjs responseError interceptor returning a status code of -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-401

I'd like to be able to handle the 401 status code in my angularjs project. I've attempted several different variations of response interceptors, but all of them return a code of -1. I'd like to understand why this is happening. Using Angularjs v1.5.8.

```
myApp.factory('httpResponseInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    responseError: function (config) {
      console.log(config.status);
      //The above prints out -1 to the console
      return config;
    }
  };
});

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpResponseInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is CORS issue, CORS is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.
You must enable CORS from server side.